# Teens concerned about impregnation through clothes

Tags: pregnancy

How active are you online? How much do you browse the internet?

I was surprised to see that many teens ask the same question regarding what is called **Dry Humping**, which, in definition is:

> dry humping is the process of two people repeatedly moving up and down and back and forth on top of each other fully clothed( or missing various pieces, but the penis must not come in contact with the vagina with out some sort of fabric seperating them ex: boxers,panties, or even sheets!!)

We all know that the basic rule for impregnation is that the sperm must come in contact with the egg, and even be able to fertilize it. While sperm can get through clothes, semen (but this is yet been proven or disproved) gets stuck, thus the sperm dies.

What is your opinion about this? If two people are on top of each other, fully clothed, and the male comes to ejaculation, is there any chance that pregnancy can happen, in the **realistic** look at it (and not some probability or statistical way)?

I would love to see the feedback of such a great community.

Comment: Yakshemash ! Why do you care about this ? Unless both people are wearing paper thin underwear and there is a LOT of ejaculation (See Peter North) , nothing can happen. Dry hump to your hearts content. Chenqui.

Comment: I care about this because I was a teen once, and my partner and I do this without realizing the risks (it is our only choice), and I am planning on writing a few articles about it to make more teens aware.

Comment: Aware of what? The incredibly minimal chances?

Comment: Torben, although the chances are "incredibly minimal", it is still a risk, even I worry about it, don't you think it is worthwhile making teens aware of it too?

Comment: This isn't a parenting question. Not really a question at all as it merely trying to elicit a discussion. That doesn't fit in the goal of stackexchange.

Comment: Children don't cause accidents. Accidents cause children.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Chance: yes. Realistic: no where in hell.

Semen don't have any form of intelligence when trying to reach the egg to fertilize, so every movement is basically random. The semen in question would need to penetrate the fabric of whatever they are wearing, find and enter the vagina, survive the long way and very hostile environment and still hit the egg. Chances of this to happen are abysmally low. I would have to calculate it, but I think chances for the semen to accidentally quantum-teleport to their destination might be higher.

Comment: Greatly put. I am gathering information for a few articles and loved to see the feedback of such a community. On the biology side, I've asked my MSc and PhD biologists friends, as scientists, they say it is fairly possible, depending on the amount of sperm and clothing present. That's statistically speaking. Realistically, it is like you put it. Thanks.

Comment: I find that there are very few questions in biology where the answers is "Never, absolutely impossible".  There are always some kind of exceptions.

Comment: Indeed, because biologists are scientists, and when the chance is there, even if it is magically minimal, they must not say "Never, absolutely impossible"

Comment: +1 just for using the phrase "semen to accidentally quantum-teleport to their destination".  I will laugh about that for the rest of the evening.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming this is all that happens, the chance of pregnancy is minuscule.

However, when two teens are together, partially undressed and going at it, there is a very real risk of those panties coming off in the heat of the moment. That's the where the risk of pregnancy is, and it's a real risk indeed, as anyone who was once half of a pair of teens in a car should well realize. The closer kids are to "real" sex, the closer they are to real sex!

Comment: Hence, inform about condoms, and why one should always carry (a fresh one) with you.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember, in Poland it takes couples, on average, three months to get pregnant. It means that having sex several times during the fertile part of the cycle, having the full amount of ejaculated sperm inside the vagina/uterus still gives about one-in-three chance of getting pregnant.

While *dry humping* could somehow possibly maybe get the couple pregnant, I think that if it happens, the two can simply go and take part in a national lottery, win it, and they're good for life.

Comment: Yes. Basically, there is 30%-50% chance getting pregnant in perfect conditions, so considering all those barriers in this type of "sexual interaction" it is really a small chance. Maybe winning the lottery is a better chance.